# How can I insert a new line of string in a specific position with python3

Tags: python

The difficulty of my problem lies in the "specific position". I want to write a script that first test if some specific string existed in the code (of a file), then I include a header file at the end of all the other includes.
E.g. If I find `SomeString` in this file, then after

```
#include <oldfile1.h>
#include "oldfile2.h"
```

insert  `#include "someheaderfile.h"`

I am looking for an elegant solution if possible.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Python? Python uses `import`, not `#include`.

Comment: Would `SomeString` be in the original file or one of the imported files?

Comment: The file I read is using C++, but I do not think this is important. The problem is that I do not know the number index of the line and I want to insert another include or import after that.

Comment: @themadpsychologist They're using Python to edit C code.

Comment: ```SomeString```would be in the original file.

Comment: the specification after which header it shoudl go is quite vague, but you can go dirty this way: `if 'SomeString' in file_content: file_content.replace("#include after_this_header", "#include after_this_header\n #include my_new_header")`

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Yes, but the problem is I do not know what is ```after_this_header```, actually I need to search recursively every file in a folder. So, the ```after_this_header``` is not fixed and that is exactly the difficult part.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Please don't post answers in the comments.

Comment: I'm confused. Why wouldn't it work to read the file, check the beginning of each line to see whether it's an `#include`, and insert your `#include` before the first line that isn't?

Comment: I've never tried this myself, but this question looks promising: [How do I write to the middle of a text file while reading its contents?](/q/16556944/4518341) Also this one if the line index is known: [Insert line at middle of file with Python?](/q/10507230/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(fname,'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
    if 'SomeString' in s:
        sl = s.splitlines()
        for i, x in enumerate(sl):
            if x[0] != '#':
                out = sl[:i] + ['#include "someheaderfile.h"'] + sl[i+1:]
                break

with open(fname,'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(out))
```

You read your file, check if your string is in it. Then you read line by line to locate the end of the header region and you reconstruct your list of lines, adding your extra header.

Then your rewrite your file by joining the new list.

Comment: Thanks! ```if x[0] != '#':``` is the logic I need.

Comment: Your welcome! Think about upvote/accept the answer of that helped!